# how to re-number filtered elements in result set

Tags: xslt

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
    <chapter>
        <section name="a">...</section>
        <section name="b">...</section>
        <section name="c">...</section>
        <section name="d">...</section>
        <section name="e">...</section>
        ...
    </chapter>
    <appendix>
        <section name="reference">...</section>
    </appendix>
</book>
```

Hi, I want to output all the **`sections`** under `chapter` and `appendix` nodes. The sections under appendix will be printed out definitely. But **not all sections under chapter are allowed to print out**, they depend on some external condition (if the section name is in allowed list which passed in from java application).

Also `sections` under `chapter` should be output with correct **sequence number before section name** which looks like the following:

**Desired result**

1. b ...
2. d ...

(which means section a, c, e are filtered out)

My question is how I can produce the above desired output for `//chapter/section`? Any hints or help is highly appreciated

**My XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ex="http://example.com/namespace" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="validChapters" />

    <xsl:function name="ex:isValidChapter" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="str-in" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($validChapters, $str-in)">
                <xsl:sequence select="true()" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="false()" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="appendix" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        ...
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="appendix">
        ...
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        ...
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//chapter/section">
        <xsl:if test="ex:isValidChapter(@name)">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:number format="1."/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Explain more clearly, with sample XML data and desired output.

Comment: Where is "allowed list" stored?

Comment: the allowed list is passed in from java application, and in the form of comma separated string so as to use contains function

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply to provide a `count=` attribute to your `<xsl:number>` instruction:

```
        <xsl:number format="1." count="section[ex:isValidChapter(@name)]"/>
```

Thus in numbering the sections, only sections that are "valid" will be counted, so the numbering will be correct.

Note also that you need to modify your template that says:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter" />
```

since `<chapter>` is not a child of the root node. (It is a child of the document element, `<book>`.) E.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/book">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter" />
```

Also, your function doesn't need a choose/when/otherwise to turn a boolean result into a boolean. It can be shortened to:

```
<xsl:function name="ex:isValidChapter" as="xs:boolean">
   <xsl:param name="str-in" as="xs:string"/>
   <xsl:sequence select="contains($validChapters, $str-in)"/>
</xsl:function>
```